# Opening and closing tags are different colors Sublime

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3, sublimetext2

I'm watching this tutorial on React and I notice that my div and h2 tags are different colors on Sublime. I'm not sure if this is an issue with my code or Sublime but how can I get this fixed. I'm using the Material Brogrammer theme with Sublime 3.

[image]

Comment: have you tried removing the `</img>`? It's not valid HTML. Instead do `<img src="..." />`. `<img>` is a void tag

Answer (score 0):

Use a plugin on sublime to set syntax to JSX files

Comment: I have this package installed. Not sure if it's doing anything https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel